# How to generate a random number in a list from a range

Tags: python-3.x, list, random

I have a dice program, and i have this:

```
 import random
 if how_much == "32":
        dice_32 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]
        print(dice_32)
```

How i can made this shorter, to the list generates a number from 1 to 32 ( or bigger ) without making the list even bigger?

Comment: in this case you are just printing the list instead of random number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random integer between two endpoints in Python with the `random.randint()` function. This spans the full **[x, y]** interval and may include both endpoints:

```
>>> random.randint(0, 10)
7
>>> random.randint(500, 50000)
18601
```

With `random.randrange()`, you can exclude the right-hand side of the interval, meaning the generated number always lies within **[x, y]** and will always be smaller than the right endpoint:

```
>>> random.randrange(1, 10)
5
```

If you need to generate random floats that lie within a specific **[x, y]** interval, you can use `random.uniform()`, which plucks from the continuous uniform distribution:

```
>>> random.uniform(20, 30)
27.42639687016509
>>> random.uniform(30, 40)
36.33865802745107
```

To pick a random element from a non-empty sequence (like a list or a tuple), you can use `random.choice()`. There is also `random.choices()` for choosing multiple elements from a sequence with replacement (duplicates are possible):

```
>>> items = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
>>> random.choice(items)
'four'

>>> import random
>>> random.randint(1,32)
22

>>> random.randint(1,35)
17

>>> random.randint(1,100)
10

>>> random.randint(1,100)
100

>>> random.randint(1,100)
81

>>> random.randrange(1,100)
91

>>> random.choice(range(100))
60

>>> random.choice(range(100))
55

>>> random.choice(range(100))
58
```